# Reseting Macbook Pro keyboard and trackpad's power usage on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb, macbook-pro, power

I recently installed a utitlity for Windows (ASUS Ai Charger) which modifies the USB ports on the computer to output more power (for charging iPads, etc). The problem is, I believe it is also giving more power to my keyboard and trackpad. And now, neither devices are working at all, yet they work on Mac OS X.

So does anyone know the amount of power MacBook Pro (2007) keyboards and trackpads use, and how I can set these settings in Windows 7?

Comment: Do they work if you revert changes you made with the utility?

Comment: I don't think that you can revert changes in it. And it fails to unistall. But I disabled it to not open at startup.